# IF statement combo-box filled from sql c#

Tags: c#, combobox

Hi there i have a combobox filled with table from the SQL
and with this particular combobox i want to use a if statement
for example

```
if (comboBox2.Text is filled from sqL)
{
//then new form will pop out
}
Else
{
//no nothing
}
```

Comment: Check if the items count is greater than 0. `If(comboBox.Items.Count>0)`

Comment: how do i do that can u show me some coding

Comment: I have already showed in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Do you wish to add items from datasource other than SQL Table? I assume you dont, this if condition is a bad idea. Whether filling items from sqldata or manually adding items to the combobox, as @farhad Jabiyev suggested, you get the count of items first or check the associated datasource is null or empty rather than accessing combobox control directly if you are using multithreaded application.

```
if (comboBox2.Items.Count > 0)
    {
      //then new form will pop out
    }
Else
    {
      //no nothing
    }
```